# How to make a work item in azure boards run in recurrence manners

Tags: azure-devops, workitem, azure-boards

My requirement is - create work item in azure boards and run in a recurrence manner, something like scheduled jobs.

I created a sample project, created a custom processes, custom work item type and have created a sample work item using the above. But i want to run this work item at regular cadence (in recurrence manner),

I don't want to create each time the same work item to achieve the same, the reason is, I have job cadence daily, weekly, monthly, fortnightly, twice a week..

can you suggest a solution here?

Comment: @Srividhya Ganesan Hi, Is my answer helpful to your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically create work items on a regular basis,I think you need to use [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=5.1
```

Sample request body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample"
  }
]
```

With this rest api, you can write a script to periodically trigger this rest api to create a custom work item.

Here is my sample powershell script,:

```
$uri = 'https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=5.1';

[array]$requestList = @();
$requestObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject;
$requestObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "op" -Value 'add';
$requestObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "path" -Value "/fields/System.Title";
$requestObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "from" -Value "null";
$requestObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "value" -Value "Sample";
$requestList += @($requestObj);

$body = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($requestList);
Write-Host $body;

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json-patch+json;

Write-Host $response;
```

You can also use the [Windows task scheduler](https://sharepointeducation.wordpress.com/2019/01/19/scheduling-powershell-script-in-windows-task-scheduler/) to run your script to achieve timing trigger.